# installing DNN how to set up connection string in the web.config

Tags: string, installation, connection, dotnetnuke

I have a hosting account with the following Connection Strings:

workstation id=mungboimedia.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=xxxyanmxxx_SQLLogin_1;pwd=xxxxxxxxxx;data source=mungboimedia.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=mungboimedia

How do i set up this connection string in the web.config so that my DNN may be installed. I am confused how to set up this connction string in the web.config, Database is MSSQL 2014 Express.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this question already in the [DNN Community forum](https://dnncommunity.org/forums/aft/3093). In short: there is no need to do that, the connection can be set up during the installation process.